# ASP.net Windows authentication compared to Forms authentication using ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, asp.net-authentication

I was wondering if someone could explain the difference between forms authentication using the ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, and Windows authentication.  When would one be used over the other and what would the benefit be?

I am working on an application which initially will be using the SqlMembershipProvider and ASP.net membership, roles, and profiles.  But there is a possibility down the road where authentication will need to be done from Active Directory, and I would like to plan ahead so that the change will result in minimal refactoring. Has anyone had similar experience and could provide insight to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is in the data that is sent up from the client.  In Windows Authentication, IE will pass the AD tokens up to the website (ie: it will act like Single Sign On).  Using forms authentication will require the user to type in their username and password regardless of the backend store being used to authenticate the user.